# How to remove a specific randomly chosen element from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm doing a simple python game for a school project and it is like a playing card game. But i don't know how to remove the card I've played.
Basically, I have a pack of 7 cards and i randomly choose one card to be played if my attack > than opponents defese I won, and my card should not be used anymore. I'm doing all based on lists and strings, How can I remove the card who was randomly chosen?

```
 baralho1=[]        
 baralho1 += random.sample(MasterList, 7)
 print("\nEste é o teu baralho:\n",baralho1)
 baralho2=[]
 baralho2 += random.sample(MasterList, 7)
 a=random.choice(baralho1)
```

How do I remove "a" from the "baralho1"?

Comment: it probably would be a better idea to generate pseudo-random index and pop card from list using it

Comment: Do you want to remove 1 occurence of `a`, or all occurences?

Comment: @user202729 all!!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I remove "a" from the "baralho1"?

```
baralho1.remove(a)
```

Please read the documentation on [mutable sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).